# Remove column default in rails migration

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, rails-migrations

I have this migration in my rails project

```
class ChangeColumnDefaultOfTemp < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def up
    change_column_null :states, :temp, false, ''
    change_column_default :states, :temp, ''
  end

  def down
    change_column_null :states, :temp, true
    change_column :states, :temp, :string, default: nil
  end
end
```

I am able to revert the not null constraint with

```
change_column_null :states, :temp, true
```

but this command

```
change_column :states, :temp, :string, default: nil
```

Is not giving me expected result

```
rake db:migrate

temp  | character varying(255)  | not null default ''::character varying
```

---

```
rake db:rollback


temp  | character varying(255)  | default NULL::character varying

-- Expected is
temp  | character varying(255)  |
```

**Note:** Looking for something similar to

```
ALTER [ COLUMN ] column DROP DEFAULT
```

[ref](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/sql-altertable.html)

Answer (score 2):

I thinks it is a common bug in Rails, when you have a `string` type column. I would just go with **raw SQL**:

```
class ChangeColumnDefaultOfTemp < ActiveRecord::Migration
  # ...
  def down
    execute <<-SQL
      ALTER TABLE states ALTER COLUMN temp DROP DEFAULT;
    SQL
  end
end
```